# Keeping a 'revisionable' copy of Neo4j data in the file system; how?

Tags: neo4j

The idea is to have git or a git-like system (users, revision tracking, branches, forks, etc) store the 'master copy' of objects and relationships.

Since the master copy is on the filesystem, any changes can be checked in, tracked, and backed up. Neo4j could then import the files and serve queries. This also gives freedom since node and connection files can be imported to any other database.

- Changes in Neo4j can be written to these files as part of the query
- Nodes and connections can be added by other means (like copying from a seed dataset)
- Nodes and connections are rarely created/updated/deleted by users
- Most of the usage is where Neo4j shines: querying
- Due to these two, the performance penalty on importing can be safely ignored

**What's the best way to set this up?**

***If this isn't wise; how come?***

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do that, but it will be lot of work which would not have a real value. IMHO.

With unmanaged extension for Transaction Event API you are able to store information about each transaction onto disk in your common file format.

Here is the some information about Transaction Event API - http://graphaware.com/neo4j/transactions/2014/07/11/neo4j-transaction-event-api.html

Could you please tell us more about the use case and how would design that system?

Answer (score 0):

In general nothing keeps you from just keeping neo4j database files around (zipped).

Otherwise I would probably use a format which can be quickly exported / imported and diffed too.

So very probably csv files with node-file per label ordered by a sensible key

And then relationship-files between pairs of nodes, with neo4j-import you can recover that data quickly into a graph again.

If you want to write changes to the files you have to make sure they are replayable (appends + updates + deletes) , i.e. you have to chose a format which is more or less a transaction-log (which Neo4j already has).

If you want to do it yourself the TransactionHandler is what you want to look at. Alternatively you could dump the full database to a snapshot at times you request.

There are plans to add point-in-time recovery on the existing tx-logs, which I think would also address your question.